# replace specific ip address using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I wan to replace a specific IP to another so say localhost to 0.0.0.0

`sed -i -e 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/g'` doesn't seem to work

also tried `sed -i -e 's/localhost/0\.0\.0\.0/g'` doesnt work either

sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: I have a file with bunch of "localhost" and I want to replace them with "0.0.0.0"

Comment: @user1870400 Does your file have a bunch of  `localhost` or a bunch of `ip=localhost`?  It makes a difference.  If you want good answers, you should include a short sample of one of the input files that is causing you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for asking that. It is bunch of localhost

Comment: @user1870400 You don't need to escape `.` in replacement. Looks like locale issue. Do `export LC_ALL=C`, hit enter and then try your command again.

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem - can you explain why you need to use `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples seem to work fine for me. Given the following `test.txt`

```
ip=localhost
```

The following replaces the entire `ip=localhost` with `0.0.0.0`

```
sed -i -e 's/ip=localhost/0\.0\.0\.0/g' test.txt
```

If you just want the `localhost` part replaced:

```
sed -i -e 's/localhost/0\.0\.0\.0/g' test.txt
```

will give you the following:

```
 ip=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I want to replace every file that has localhost with 0.0.0.0 and it says Sed ERR illegal byte sequence with  all of them I tried. find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/ip=localhost/0\.0\.0\.0/g' {} \;  and find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/localhost/0\.0\.0\.0/g' {} \;

Comment: Your original question didn't mention the find. You need to include all the relevant information in your question. You can either update your question or start a new one.